# How to set axios response data to variable

Tags: javascript, axios

I have sample function where I use `axios`:

```
function getPosts() {
    var response = null;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').then(function(res){
        response = res.data
    });
    return response; // null
}
```

How can be setted response data to `response` variable in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that axios returns a `Promise`.

Change your function to this:

```
function getPosts() {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').then(function(res){
        return res.data;
    });
}

// call getPosts()
getPosts()
   .then(function (data) {
      // now data contains the actual information
   })
```

Comment: I must return response data only inside my function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPosts() {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').then(function(res){
      resolve(res);
    }).catch(e) {
      reject({
        error: true,
        message: e
      })
    }
  };
}
```

Return a promise and resolve it when data will come or reject if it fails